# Is this the correct way to send state using <Link>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying currently to send object through Link. Here is my **App.js**, here the important route is **/movie/seats** and **MovieDetails** component.

```
import React from 'react';
import CinemaList from './components/XML2JS/CinemaList';
import upperNavImage from './components/Navigation/Logo.jpg';
import './App.css';
import DateTime from './components/Date and Time/dateTime';
import EventList from './components/XML2JS/EventList';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import MovieDetails from './components/Seat/MovieDetails';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <div className='upper-nav'>
          <img src={upperNavImage} alt="Upper Nav Image" className="center" />
        </div>
        <div className='lower-nav'>
          <a href="#" className="language-link">Eesti</a>
          <a href="#" className="language-link">Русский</a>
          <a href="#" className="language-link">English</a>
            <div className='dateTime'>
              <DateTime/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className='body'>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<CinemaList />} />
            <Route path="/events" element={<EventList />} />
            <Route 
              path="/movie/seats" 
              element={<MovieDetails/>} 
            />
          </Routes>
          {/* https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering */}
          {window.location.pathname !== '/movie/seats' && <EventList />}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my object, that i want to send using link. ***(selectedEvent)***

```
// https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/components/offcanvas

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './EventList.css';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Offcanvas from 'react-bootstrap/Offcanvas';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const EventList = () => {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
  const [selectedEvent, setSelectedEvent] = useState(null);
  const [showOffcanvas, setShowOffcanvas] = useState(false);
  

  const handleShowOffcanvas = (event) => {
    setSelectedEvent(event);
    setShowOffcanvas(true);
  };

  const handleCloseOffcanvas = () => {
    setShowOffcanvas(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const params = {
      includePictures: true,
      includeGallery: true,
      includeVideos: true,
      includeLinks: true,
    };

    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/cinema/event', { params })
      .then(response => {
        setEvents(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching events:', error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="event-list-container">
      <div className="movie-grid">
        {events.map(event => (
          <div key={event.ID} className="movie-box">
            <img src={event.Images.EventMediumImagePortrait} alt="Event Poster" />
            <h3>{event.Title}</h3>
            <p>{event.OriginalTitle}</p>
            <p>Genres: {event.Genres}</p>
            <Button onClick={() => handleShowOffcanvas(event)}>Vaata lähemalt</Button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <Offcanvas show={showOffcanvas} onHide={handleCloseOffcanvas}>
        <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
          <Offcanvas.Title>Valitud film</Offcanvas.Title>
        </Offcanvas.Header>
        <Offcanvas.Body>
          {selectedEvent && (
            <>
              <h3>{selectedEvent.Title}</h3>
              <p>{selectedEvent.OriginalTitle}</p>
              <p>Rating: {selectedEvent.Rating}</p>
              <img src={selectedEvent.Images.EventMediumImagePortrait}></img>
              <p>Pikkus: {selectedEvent.LengthInMinutes} minutid</p>
              <p>Tootmisaasta: {selectedEvent.ProductionYear}</p>
              <p>Genres: {selectedEvent.Genres}</p>
              <p>{selectedEvent.shortSynopsis}</p>
              {console.log("Selected Event:", selectedEvent)}
              <Link
                to={{
                  pathname: "/movie/seats",
                  state: { selectedEvent },
                }}
              >
                <Button>Vaata kohad</Button>
              </Link>
            </>
          )}
        </Offcanvas.Body>
      </Offcanvas>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EventList;
```

selectedEvent object looks like this

Object { shortSynopsis: "Film “Valge lind: lugu imest” on, nagu 2017. aasta film “Väike ime”, südamlik film ajatust lahkusest. Bestselleri “Ime” autori uuel inspireerival raamatul “Valge lind: lugu imest” põhinev samanimeline film räägib järgmise peatükina loo Julianist (Bryce Gheisar), kellel on raskusi kohanemisega pärast seda, kui ta koolist Auggie Pullmani kohtlemise tõttu välja visati.", ID: 4263, Title: "Valge lind: lugu imest", OriginalTitle: "White Bird: A Wonder Story", ProductionYear: 2023, LengthInMinutes: 120, Images: {…}, Genres: "Draama, Kogupere, Biograafia", ShortSynopsis: "Film “Valge lind: lugu imest” on, nagu 2017. aasta film “Väike ime”, südamlik film ajatust lahkusest. Bestselleri “Ime” autori uuel inspireerival raamatul “Valge lind: lugu imest” põhinev samanimeline film räägib järgmise peatükina loo Julianist (Bryce Gheisar), kellel on raskusi kohanemisega pärast seda, kui ta koolist Auggie Pullmani kohtlemise tõttu välja visati.", Rating: "Alla 12 a. mittesoovitatav" }

Here i am trying to get some info, from "selectedEvent" object, but when i console.log(state) i am getting this response.

```
Object { pathname: "/movie/seats", search: "", hash: "", state: null, key: "efmr9p4n" }
​
hash: ""
​
key: "efmr9p4n"
​
pathname: "/movie/seats"
​
search: ""
​
state: null
```

Where i am trying to access object

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';


const MovieDetails = (props) => {
  const state  = useLocation();
  const {selectedEvent} = state
  console.log(state)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Title: {selectedEvent.Title}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MovieDetails;
```

I am confused, what i am doing wrong. The question is: ***How can i send object using Link to another component, where i can access it ?***